# Updating a shadow field, via updateOne pre hook, in mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can anyone explain how to use the updateOne pre-hook, in mongoose (5.9.5)?

I am need to create a normalised 'shadow field' (not sure the right term) to help with certain searches. While I am able to update the shadow field during a save, I am having trouble during update.

The save pre-hook:

```
personSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    if (this.isModified('name')) {
        const name = this.name;
        if (name && name.trim().length > 0) {
            const shadowName = name.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
            this.shadowName = shadowName.toLowerCase();
        } else {;
            this.shadowName = name;
        }
    }

    // do stuff
    next();
});
```

Doing the equivalent for `updateOne` does not seem to work (`shadowName` stays with the value it was given during the initial save):

```
personSchema.pre('updateOne', function (next) {
    const name = this.name;
    if (name && name.trim().length > 0) {
        const shadowName = name.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
        this.update({}, { shadowName: shadowName.toLowerCase() });
    } else {
        this.shadowName = name;
    }

    // do stuff
    next();
});
```

The schema:

```
const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    resourceId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        uppercase: true
    },
    name:{
        type: String,
        required:true,
        index: true
    },
    // can be used for searches, but don't update directly
    shadowName: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
});
```

BTW I can confirm the hook is called, but the field is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you can't access the field values directly and instead need to leverage the `get()` and `set()` methods on the query.

Changing the pre-updateOne hook to be the following works:

```
personSchema.pre('updateOne', function (next) {
    const name = this.get('name');
    if (name && name.trim().length > 0) {
        const shadowName = name.normalize('NFD').replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, '');
        this.set('shadowName', shadowName.toLowerCase());
    } else {
        this.set('shadowName', name);
    }

    // do stuff
    next();
});
```